# Problems with line separator in Scala StringLike

Tags: scala, unicode

When getting input that is copied and pasted from browser HTML I sometimes get Unicode LINE SEPARATOR's into my app:

`\u2028`

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm

Here it is within quotes: " "

I'm splitting my input up in lines because reasons, but these are unfortunately not picked up by `StringLike.lines`:

https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.11.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/StringLike.scala#L76

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Could be a bug, the same is true for \u2424 "SYMBOL FOR NEWLINE". You could try to [report it](https://issues.scala-lang.org/). Also, as a workaround, a good candidate for the *pimp my library* pattern

Answer (score 0):

The line of code linked in your question defines the criteria `StringLike.lines` uses for line breaks:

```
private def isLineBreak(c: Char) = c == LF || c == FF
```

`LL` and `FF` are defined as:

```
private final val LF = 0x0A
private final val FF = 0x0C
```

The Unicode character `\u2028` is not the same as either of these. In the scala interpreter, we can check this:

`scala> val x = "\u2028"`

`x: String = " "`

```
scala> val LF = 0x0A
LF: Int = 10

scala> val FF = 0x0C
FF: Int = 12

scala> x == LF || x == FF
res0: Boolean = false
```

This is the reason why the `StringLike.lines` does not capture the given Unicode line break.

I would guess that the reason why the Scala function is written in this way, i.e. why it uses only these ASCII line breaks (LF and FF), is so that no assumption needs to be made about the string encoding, i.e. UTF-8 vs ISO-8859-1, etc.